# When using wireless, SSH connexion stops after "expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY"

Tags: ssh

When on wireless (interface `wlp2s0b1`), I can't connect to my SSH server, but when using Ethernet (interface `enp1s0f0`), I can.

- Both interfaces are on the same network.
- Connexion stops after `debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY`.
- I'm using Manjaro Linux.
- I've no firwalls.
- On the server, `/var/log/auth.log` shows nothing.

What I've tried and didn't worked :

- Tweaking the MTU (tried a bunch of values): `sudo ip li set mtu 1500 dev wlp2s0b1`.
- Changing the port (from `22` to `2222`).
- Setting the KexAlgorithms: `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521 user@host`

Thanks!

Comment: You're attempting to debug what looks like a network issue at the application level, effectively yielding no usable information. Try looking at the link level with Wireshark to gather actionable information that can help you track down your issue. ). Also, I doubt this is a question about *systems administration in a business environment* so I'm voting to close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: it was a driver issue.

My config:

- PC: MacBook Pro late 2012
- Wireless chip: BCM4331
- OS: Manjaro Linux

The `b43` driver is known to have some issues. I installed the `broadcom-wl` driver and now it works fine.

Some resources about this issue:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Broadcom_wireless#SSH_freeze_for_BCM4331_with_b43
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-ssh-via-wifi-with-b43-firmware-via-cable-all-ok/65668